# CAML OrderBy onlt works for certain fields

Tags: sharepoint, caml

So, this OrderBy works

`<Query>
     <OrderBy>
         <FieldRef Name="Title" Ascending="True"/>
     </OrderBy>
</Query>`

and this one doesn't

`<Query>
     <OrderBy>
         <FieldRef Name="SortOrder" Ascending="True"/>
     </OrderBy>
</Query>`

I'm at a loss. Both are fields in my SharePoint List, SortOrder was a "Number" but I changed it to a "Single Line of Text" (same as Title).

Note: If I remove the  tag NO OrderBy works.

Comment: NOte sure where the code went.

Comment: I found your code in your message body. We still need some more information. What happens when you run the one that doesn't work? Do you get a specific error message? Does it cause a hang? Does it give you the wrong results (and if so, could you be specific?)?

Comment: The code didn't show up initially but I can see it now. Is it visible to you? The only difference is in the FieldRef Name. Both are valid fields in my list.

Comment: No errors, it just doesn't sort. I can put XXXXX in instead of SortOrder and get the same results.

Comment: That should say, If I remove the Query tag no OrderBy works.

Comment: If I put in Override="True" the results are different but still not sorted by SortOrder. Additionally, most values for SortOrder are NULL, only 5 of 72 have values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out that this is an "Internal Name" issue. The creator of the list originally named the field "Sort Order" then changed it to "SortOrder". So the internal name is "Sort_x0020_Order".

Duh.

Thanks everyone for your input.